# Fixing the animation angle on ellipse

Tags: javascript, animation, rxjs, spark-ar-studio

I use this formula to calculate the angle on an ellipse
`Phi = atan(y*py/x*px)`, where `py` and `px` are parameters of an ellipse. When the animation crosses -PI and PI, it changes its direction by PI rad.

I use RxJs and don't know how to make a swap at right time. Maybe I need to subscribe to some event?

[arrows showing the orientation of the object that I get, its moving in clockwise direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqrbY.jpg)

Comment: Can you please provide some example code to help us understand what you are asking?

Comment: @laptou this code used in facebook ar, Ive made an object and this is how I assign its position

 this.aPos =
 Reactive.point(
   Reactive.mul(
    Reactive.cos(this.angle), this.rX
   ),
   Reactive.add(
    Reactive.mul(
     Reactive.sin(this.angle), this.rY
    ),
    10 
   ),
   0
 );

Comment: -Pi and Pi are marked in the wrong position on your image. What you marked are actually -Pi/2 and Pi/2 radians

Comment: @TamasHegedus   Oh yeah sorry that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Use [Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) instead of atan.

Comment: it is still from -PI to PI. I think the question is more about how to add/sub PI at extremal points...

Comment: @lisichkaggg -PI to PI is fine, that's a whole circle. If your arrows still show the wrong direction that means there is an error in your rendering logic. If you could provide some of your sourcecode that we can run would be great. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)